# How do the updates to webAPK take place on changing manifest.json served at same origin?

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I am testing the scenarios where the update to manifest.json result in the update to the progressive web app. According to the google documentation, https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#update-webapk, the updates are checked after every 1 day or 30 days interval depending on the server. I tried changing my manifest and changed my system time to advance by a day, but I was unable to view any changes in the web app. Can someone help me, in how exactly will the update to manifest be propagated to my web app installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered in a similar question that I previously asked. Refer to this link [When does a progressive web app update on making a change to its manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676685/when-does-a-progressive-web-app-update-on-making-a-change-to-its-manifest-file/60408617#60408617).